# Block the original referer (parent) in a invisible pixel on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have mounted a system in which if a user enters a page any is shown an invisible pixel (1x1) of an external URL within an iframe.

The problem is that in that external URL that loads (and is invisible to the user) should not appear as referer the original URL. So to avoid that, what I do is use a domain in between (that redirects to the final domain). This way, if a user for example enters Stackoverflow.com and loads the pixel that loads a URL as example1.com into an iframe that in turn loads examplefinal.com, this way examplefinal.com receives a request Of example1.com and not of Stackoverflow.com

Well, on paper this should work, and it actually works, but not always. In 2 or 3% of the time I receive as referer the domain where the user (in the example would be Stackoverflow.com) instead of example1.com which is what I need to happen in 100% of the time. I have even tried to insert two different domains in between that redirect between them to make it harder for me to pick up the original domain, but the same thing happens.

Anyone have a solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you add the logical flow its quite hard to deduce what you are saying. urls and invisible pixels....??

Comment: @Seabizkit The flow its simple, I have a one site (example1.com) with a javascript tag that display/show a invisible iframe (pixel) that load any src (any URL) , for example test2.com . The problem is that test2.com can see that the referer URL is example1.com and I need to avoid that. What I do now is specify a src such as test3.com in the iframe/pixel that redirects to the destination URL. In this case the flow is: user load site example1.com and the iframe load test3.com and this redirects to test2.com, so with this the final destination (test2.com) see as referer test3.com

Comment: But the problem is that this does not happen 100% of the times, because on some occasions the example1.com continues to appear as referer... I need a solution where the referer is ALWAYS test3.com

Comment: OK I think I'm following with much effort for clarity, for someone else who 
may reading this, just simplify it by saying you have a web page with an iframe, you want the refer url for the iframe to be different from its source. Drop the words [pixel, invisible, parent and what not], its an iframe and you want to change the url refer, and its not listening as expected.

Comment: Post some code. so we can see what you have